# Solution to $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{a u}}{2\mathrm{cosh}\left(\frac{u^2}{2}-b\right)+1} du$, where $a>0$ and $b>0$

Tags: integration, approximate-integration

Can someone please help me in finding the solution to the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{a u}}{2\mathrm{cosh}\left(\frac{u^2}{2}-b\right)+1} du,$$ where $a>0$ and $b>0$.

I have looked at all the table integrals, tried with Mathematica, without any success. So far I have a "good'' solution only when $b$ is large enough.

This integral is a result of a research problem that I am currently working on, and it represents a major blockade in moving forward.

$\mathbf{{Update\; 1:}}$

I good approximation to this integral, in the domain that I am interested in, would be the following:

$$\int_{\sqrt{2b}}^\infty \frac{e^{a u}}{e^{\frac{u^2}{2}-b}+1} du,$$ which again I struggle to solve. Note that if +1 is removed from the denominator, this integral is easy to be solved. But removing the +1 makes the solution not quite accurate.

Comment: Why are you interested in this integral? What is the context? What have you tried?

Comment: My current solution is to remove the +1 in the denominator and then I can solve it by splitting the integration domain from 0 to $\sqrt{2b}$ and from $\sqrt{2b}$ to $\infty$. However, that solution is not accurate enough when $b$ is small.

Comment: I think the residue method works.

Comment: @xpaul. Could you eleborate ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you could use
$$\int_{\sqrt{2b}}^\infty \frac{e^{a u}}{e^{\frac{u^2}{2}-b}+1} du=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \int_{\sqrt{2b}}^\infty e^{a u} \left(e^{b-\frac{u^2}{2}}\right)^{n+1}\,du$$
$$I_n=\int_{\sqrt{2b}}^\infty e^{a u} \left(e^{b-\frac{u^2}{2}}\right)^{n+1}\,du$$
$$I_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2(n+1)}}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{2 (n+1)}+b(n+1) \right) \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{b (n+1)}-\frac{a}{
   \sqrt{2(n+1)}}\right)$$

The problem will be how fast the sum converges.

Just to try, I used $a=\pi$ and $10$ terms for the summation
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
b &\sum_{n=0}^{10} (-1)^n\, I_n  &\text{exact value} \\
 0 & 332.862 & 332.396 \\
 1 & 844.917 & 841.868 \\
 2 & 2044.39 & 2031.30 \\
 3 & 4712.69 & 4669.65 \\
 4 & 10385.3 & 10264.2 \\
 5 & 21975.0 & 21668.4 \\
 6 & 44842.8 & 44124.8 \\
 7 & 88600.9 & 87019.1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$